# Vector Embeddings of Text Data: LSTM pushing all output values to 1

Tags: deep-learning, theano, lstm, word-embedding

I am using a deep learning / neural language model to encode or strings of text into a vector space. The model architecture consists of a series of convolutional layers which feed information into LSTM encoder/decoder layers. This is not code I've written, but can be seen here: https://github.com/soroushv/Tweet2Vec. The code's written with Theano.

I've already trained the model (learned the encoding parameters) and am running into trouble now as I try to encode new data (tweets, specifically). The problem: **The LSTM encoding layer is encoding each tweet as a vector of 1s**

The problem be understood by examining the output from theano.scan, which conveniently returns not just the final LSTM hidden state output, but that each after each of the 256 steps. See below:

step 0

```
[[ 0.25917339  0.25781667  0.25658038 ...,  0.25910226  0.25752231
   0.25876063]
 [ 0.2606163   0.25934234  0.25892666 ...,  0.25979728  0.25971574
   0.26056644]
 [ 0.25828436  0.25749022  0.25691608 ...,  0.25829604  0.25789574
   0.25868404]
 ...,
```

]]

step 1

```
[[ 0.73329866  0.73475593  0.73370075 ...,  0.73479998  0.7338261   0.733863  ]
 [ 0.73417366  0.73541886  0.73478198 ...,  0.7358954   0.73425269
   0.73425108]
 [ 0.73278904  0.73414212  0.73380911 ...,  0.73420793  0.73367095
   0.73390627]
 ...,
```

]]

```
step 2
[[ 0.88244921  0.88317329  0.88279039 ...,  0.88326144  0.8826766
   0.88286686]
 [ 0.88289285  0.8835054   0.88333857 ...,  0.88382012  0.88288385
   0.88304704]
 [ 0.88218391  0.88285285  0.88285559 ...,  0.88295335  0.88259971
   0.88289762]
 ...,
```

]]

step 3

```
[[ 0.95328414  0.95359486  0.95343065 ...,  0.95363271  0.95338178
   0.95346349]
 [ 0.95347464  0.95373732  0.95366573 ...,  0.9538722   0.95347077
   0.95354074]
 [ 0.95317024  0.95345742  0.95345861 ...,  0.95350057  0.95334882
   0.95347661]
 ...,
```

]]

... and by step 15:
step 15

```
[[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 ...,
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]]
```

I've verified that the output from the last convolutional layer is legitimate. It looks like:

```
[[[ 0.02103661  0.06566209  0.03910736 ...,  0.02350483  0.05625576
    0.03399094]
  [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.04917431  0.00619121 ...,  0.          0.04114747  0.        ]
  ...,
  [ 0.02622109  0.01024228  0.04368387 ...,  0.04718351  0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.01217926  0.04057767  0.0250682  ...,  0.          0.03617524
  ...,...]]
```

and is of the correct shape.

So I am hoping to gain some understanding as to what is happening and how to fix it. Here is the code for the from the LSTM class. To the best of my understanding, the above convolutional output is fed as the input to calc_output below. All of this code (and the rest) is in the linked github. Thank you

```
def calc_output(self, inputs, **kwargs):

    input = inputs[0]
    mask = inputs[self.mask_idx] if self.mask_idx is not None  else None
    h_beg = inputs[self.h_beg_idx] if self.h_beg_idx is not None  else None
    cell_beg = inputs[self.cell_beg_idx] if self.cell_beg_idx is not None  else None
    if input.ndim > 3:
        input = T.flatten(input, 3)

    input = input.dimshuffle(1, 0, 2)
    seq_len, num_batch, _ = input.shape
    W_st = T.concatenate([self.W_i, self.W_f, self.W_c, self.W_o], axis=1)
    U_st = T.concatenate([self.U_i, self.U_f, self.U_c, self.U_o], axis=1)
    b_st = T.concatenate([self.b_i, self.b_f, self.b_c, self.b_o], axis=0)

    if self.precompute:
        input = T.dot(input, W_st) + b_st

    non_seqs = [U_st]

    if self.peepholes:
        non_seqs += [self.W_pci,
                     self.W_pcf,
                     self.W_pco]
    if not self.precompute:
        non_seqs += [W_st, b_st]

    def gate_data(wt_mat, gate_id):
        return wt_mat[:, gate_id * self.output_units:(gate_id + 1) * self.output_units]

    def step(i_t, c_tm1, h_tm1, *args):
        if not self.precompute:
            i_t = T.dot(i_t, W_st) + b_st
        gates = i_t + T.dot(h_tm1, U_st)
        if self.grad_clip:
            gates = theano.gradient.grad_clip(
                gates, -self.grad_clip, self.grad_clip)
        ingate = gate_data(gates, 0)
        forgetgate = gate_data(gates, 1)
        cell_input = gate_data(gates, 2)
        outgate = gate_data(gates, 3)

        if self.peepholes:
            ingate += c_tm1*self.W_pci
            forgetgate += c_tm1*self.W_pcf

        ingate = self.i_gate_act(ingate)
        forgetgate = self.f_gate_act(forgetgate)
        cell_input = self.c_gate_act(cell_input)

        cell = forgetgate*c_tm1 + ingate*cell_input

        if self.peepholes:
            outgate += cell*self.W_pco
        outgate = self.o_gate_act(outgate)

        hid = outgate*self.o_gate_act(cell)

        return [cell, hid]

    sequences = input
    step_fun = step

    ones = T.ones((num_batch, 1))
    if not isinstance(self.cell_beg, BaseLayer):
        cell_beg = T.dot(ones, self.cell_beg)

    if not isinstance(self.h_beg, BaseLayer):
        h_beg = T.dot(ones, self.h_beg)

    cell_out, hid_out = theano.scan(
        fn=step_fun,
        sequences=sequences,
        outputs_info=[cell_beg, h_beg],
        go_backwards=self.back_rnn,
        truncate_gradient=self.gradient_steps,
        non_sequences=non_seqs,
        strict=True)[0]
    if self.no_return_seq:
        hid_out = hid_out[-1]
    else:
        hid_out = hid_out.dimshuffle(1, 0, 2)
        if self.back_rnn:
            hid_out = hid_out[:, ::-1]

    return hid_out
```

Comment: Likely cause: `tanh` only outputs values between [-1.0, 1.0], but your optimization objective is too large. You should do a proper scaling.

Comment: @Kh40tiK This makes sense, thanks for the response. If I follow, that means I want to divide each value in the tensors by the maximum value **before** applying the activation functions?

Comment: A simple solution would be adding a pure linear layer on top of the LSTM output, so that no need to preprocess data.

Comment: @Kh40tiK Does that mean passing the return value of [cell, hid] in step through a linear layer? Thanks for your help, I'm knew to a lot of this!